# Reducing file size of printed PDFs in browser

Tags: javascript, pdf, firefox, canvas, printing

I need my web application (react based) to generate a pdf file. This file will include text, tables and canvas with generated content.

I decided to use the build-in printing capabilities of the browser to achieve this (I did also try [pdfkit](http://pdfkit.org) and [react-pdf](https://react-pdf.org/) but decided that doing the layout with html and css would work best).

The problem is that the resulting PDF files were relatively large (above 10MB, while around 1MB would be the acceptable maximum).

I did try to reduce the size by generating JPEGs with `canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8)` and using the dataURL instead of the canvas.

This does reduce the file size in Chrome and Safari but not in Firefox.

Using Inkscape to import the PDF and then export as SVG and then inspecting it with a text editor (please tell me that there is a simpler workflow) I found that Chrome and Safari indeed embed the JPEG but Firefox creates a PDF with the images embedded as PNG files.

Is there any way to change this behaviour in Firefox? The only other option I see is using a library like pdfkit to generate the PDF file from Javascript - which would come at the cost of easy customizations to the layout.

Minimal Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Forum_romanum_1880.jpg" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Print to PDF results in less than 200KB with Google Chrome and more than 1MB with Firefox

Comment: @HelderSepu what code do you need? Minimal problem code is: JPEG on HTML page being printed to pdf by firefox.

Comment: Moritz see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @HelderSepu added an explicit example

Comment: Ideally you should add all your code to generated the PDF so others can reproduce it, you talked about a canvas but your example does not include any canvas

Comment: The problem can be broken down to the minimal example of just one jpg image. My canvas is converted to an jpg of 80% quality with the code posted. The pdf is generated by the browsers printing function. Generating the pdf in js is what I want to avoid doing.

Comment: Moritz Don't explain your issue in the comments, edit the OP. ... and the best explanation is an MCVE

Comment: @HelderSepu I did add an MCVE - just try it in Chrome and Firefox. There is no further code required to recreate the problem I just did a lot of explaining why I care about this behaviour in firefox. Thanks for helping me optimize the question!

Comment: In your OP you mention canvas, that is not anywhere in your example

Answer (score 0):

If you print your own web, use Chrome headless and reduce image size by [here](https://dev.to/niick007/how-to-compress-image-size-without-losing-quality-in-php-4d2h)